# Search feature with async state in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm only setting state when a user presses enter whenever the input value changes

The user is then directed to a separate page with the search results

Looks like

```
handleSearch(e){
   this.setState({
    searchValue: e.target.value
   }, ((value)=>{
      if(e.key === 'Enter'){ 
       history.push('/search/')
      } 
   })(this.state.searchValue));


}

<input onKeyPress={this.handleSearch} />
```

Then in the component handling search results

```
class SearchResults extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        results : [],
        grabbedSearch: '',
        resultMessage: ''
    }

    this.grabSearchResults = this.grabSearchResults.bind(this);
 }

  componentWillUpdate(){
      this.grabSearchResults() 
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.grabSearchResults();
  }

  grabSearchResults(){
    //API calls to grab results
  }

  render(){
    return (<div>
      {results}
    </div>)
  }
```

The problem is I'm always getting the state before the current one so a search for "animals" will result in "animal" where the 's' is missing.

I'm trying to to prevent sending an api request every time the user enters a key which is why I have the check if the key is an "enter"

Comment: `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` has access to next props. Just pass it to `grabSearchResult(nextProps)` and use it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are calling `grabSearchResults()` on `componentWillUpdate` function at which point the state/props hold the previous value.

You should make use of `componentDidUpdate` function.

Also since you might be setting a state in `grabSearchResults` function, you must **provide a check** before calling `grabSearchResults` in `componentDidMount` or else your app will go in an infinite loop

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
      if(prevProps.searchValue !== this.props.searchValue) {
          this.grabSearchResults() 
      }
  }
```